# How to add a custom image for the textfield in UIsearchbar iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar, swift2

I am trying to create a custom search bar. I want to add a custom image for the textfield in the search bar. I set the searchbarstyle minimal. I used the following code to change the background image. it doesn't fit well. This outlets are added programmatically

```
let srchtextfld: UITextField = srchbr.valueForKey("searchField") as! UITextField

    srchtextfld.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Rounded Rectangle 1 copy 3.png")!).CGColor
```

I am Getting the below image

[image]

I want to add this type of image as its background

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You want to set Background color from the image or background image for the textfield of search bar?

Comment: I want to add this as the background image for the textfield

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the background image then property is background not backgroundColor see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html) . So you do like this

```
srchtextfld.background  = UIImage(named: "Rounded Rectangle 1 copy 3.png")!
```

Also remember

> When set, the image referred to by this property replaces the standard
>   appearance controlled by the borderStyle property. Background images
>   are drawn in the border rectangle portion of the text field. Images
>   you use for the text field’s background should be able to stretch to
>   fit.

Plus

> UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, custom background images are ignored.

Comment: CALayer does not have a member background. When i use srchtextfld.background, I get the image as shown in the question.

Comment: Sorry you need to call that on UITextField not layer of textfield

Comment: It's not showing up. Dat's y used the code in the question (as backgroundcolor).

Comment: When setting it as the backgroundcolor, layout issues arise for different devices